# Filtering / subrequest to get results

Tags: python, api, eve

> Mongodb

```
 db.entity.find()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5563a4c5567b3104c9ad2951"),
        "section" : "section1",
        "chapter" : "chapter1",
        ...
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5563a4c5567b3104c9ad2951"),
        "section" : "section1",
        "chapter" : "chapter2",
        ...
},....
```

In my database, the collections `entity` contain mainly `section` and `chapter`. Only `chapter` values are unique and when we query mongo for a given section it will return several results (one section matches with many chapters).

**What I need to do is to get all collections of a given section, it's as simple as that.**

> settings.py

```
URL_PREFIX = "api"

API_VERSION = "v1"

ALLOWED_FILTERS = ['*']

schema = {
    'section': {
        'type': 'string',
    },  
    'chapter': {
        'type': 'string',
    },
}

entity = {
    'item_title': 'entity',
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],

    'cache_control': '',
    'cache_expires': 0,

    'url': 'entity/<regex("\w+"):section>/section',

    'schema': schema
}

DOMAIN = {
    'entity': entity,
}
```

> run.py

```
from eve import Eve

if __name__ == '__main__':                      
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> What I tried

```
curl -L -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/entity/23/section
```

> OUTPUT

```
{ 
  "_status": "ERR",
  "_error": {
    "message": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
    "code": 404
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get all entities of one section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to write the url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/entity?where=section=='section32'
```

please have a look at this python-eve.org/features.html#filtering

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/entity/section23/section
```

You want to use `section23` in your url since that's what matches both the regex and the actual value stored on the database.

You might also want to change the url to:

```
'url': 'entity/<regex("\w+"):section>'
```

Which would allow for urls like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/entity/section23
```

Which is probably more semantic. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your anwser, but this doesn't change anything, the output is still `The requested URL was not found on the server ...` :/.

Comment: I actually tested your setup on a clean virtualenv and, with the changes I suggest, it works fine at my end. Maybe something is misplaced/misconfigured?